# Tags e branches antigos devem ser excluídos do repositório remoto?

Tags: git

Um dos produtos principais da minha companhia já tem uns 4 anos de vida. Nesse meio tempo muitos branches e tags foram criados, além do repositório ter sido migrado de SVN para GIT.

Por conta disso, o repositório tem muito código antigo e diversas branches que foram criadas e nunca terminadas ou excluídas após o merge com o master.

Atualmente estamos querendo desenvolver uma série de novos recursos, mas não sem antes limparmos o repositório e o próprio código. Daí é que entra a experiência de vocês: como manter um repositório Git bem organizado?

Comment: O meu ponto de vista seria melhor excluir os branches antigos ... imagina algo ... isso aconteceu cmg....
Eu criei um branch mas eu nao tinha visto que o nome desse branch ja tinha sido criado, só percebi quando fui fazer o merge .... imagina a dor de cabeça que deu ... fica a dica .... sabio mesmo eh aquele que aprende com o erro dos outros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

prefiro manter meus repositórios sempre o mais limpos possíveis.

Dessa forma, tento aplicar as seguintes regras:

- Branches que possuem código que não vai ser utilizado são excluídos. Sejam funcionalidades não terminadas, sejam teste de algo que não deu certo. Acredito que haja lugares melhores do que o repositório para documentar esse tipo de "falha".
- Branches que já foram mesclados no master só continuam a existir se houver necessidade de roll-back da funcionalidade, como num teste num ambiente de pré-produção, contudo prefiro manter apenas tags marcando esses commits (algo como v1.2.3pre1).

Acredito que manter branches com aumenta a complexidade em entender o que está no repositório, especialmente quando chega algum membro novo no time. Além disso, sempre acabo perdendo algum tempo revisando o que já está abandonado

Answer (score 5):

Não existe uma solução única, o que recomendo é dar uma pesquisada [nos vários tipos de *workflows*](https://www.atlassian.com/git/workflows) e ver o que se encaixa melhor para a forma de trabalho da sua empresa. Independente de qual seja escolhido, quando um for escolhido, aderência a ele implicará em limpar a bagunça.

- [Git Workflows by Atlassian](https://www.atlassian.com/git/workflows)
- [GitHub Flow](http://scottchacon.com/2011/08/31/github-flow.html)
- [Gitflow, A successful Git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)
- [GitLab Flow](https://about.gitlab.com/2014/09/29/gitlab-flow/)

No geral, com git, não vejo muito sentido em ter tags para serem deletadas posteriormente, normalmente a função de uma tag é ter um ponto fixo de [uma versão](http://semver.org/), perder esse ponto não tem muito sentido pra mim. Agora com relação a branch, isso vai depender do workflow, [*feature branchs*](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FeatureBranch.html) normalmente tem vida curta, mas é comum também ter master, develop, e outros branches pra suporte de várias versões, que são de vida longa.